SolidJS state type unknown useContext TypeScript
In my SolidJS and SolidStart project, I declared my CartContext in my CartContext.tsx

export const CartContext = createContext<>();

const stateDefault = { ... };
export type StatesT = typeof stateDefault;

export const CartContextProvider: Component<CartContextProviderProps> = (
    props: CartContextProviderProps,
) => {
    const [state, setState] = createStore<StateT>(stateDefault);

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useCartContext = () => useContext(CartContext);

But when I use this context in my components:
const { state, setState } = useCartContext();

TypeScript gave me warning: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Okay I figured it out.
I needed to add a type at createContext()
according to the CartContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}:
export type cartContextType = {
    state: StatesT;
    setState: (state: StatesT) => void;
};
export const CartContext = createContext<cartContextType>();

Then TypeScript gave me another warning: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'cartContextType | undefined'.ts(2339)
according to this docs: https://docs.solidjs.com/reference/component-apis/create-context, you need to handle context === undefined case:
export const useCartContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(CartContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error("CartContext is not valid");
    return context;
};

